# Alter Column: option to specify conversion function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of type float that contains phone numbers - I'm aware that this is bad, so I want to convert the column from float to nvarchar(max), converting the data appropriately so as not to lose data.

The conversion can apparently be handled correctly using the STR function (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881674/cast-or-convert-a-float-to-nvarchar)), but I'm not sure how to go about changing the column type and performing the conversion without creating a temporary column. I don't want to use a temporary column because we are doing this automatically a bunch of times in future and don't want to encounter performance impact from page splits (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095490/how-to-convert-a-t-sql-column-type-and-data-in-place))

In Postgres you can add a "USING" option to your ALTER COLUMN statement that specifies how to convert the existing data. I can't find anything like this for TSQL. Is there a way I can do this in place?

Postgres example:

```
...ALTER COLUMN <column> TYPE <type> USING <func>(<column>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use a temporary column in your table, use a (temporary) column in a temporary table. In short:

1. Create temp table with PK of your table + column you want to change (in the correct data type, of course)
2. select data into temp table using your conversion method
3. Change data type in actual table
4. Update actual table from temp table values

If the table is large, I'd suggest doing this in batches. Of course, if the table isn't large, worrying about page splits is premature optimization since doing a complete rebuild of the table and its indexes after the conversion would be cheap. Another question is: why nvarchar(max)? The data is phone numbers. Last time I checked, phone numbers were fairly short (certainly less than the 2 Gb that nvarchar(max) can hold) and non-unicode. Do some domain modeling to figure out the appropriate data size and you'll thank me later. Lastly, why would you do this "automatically a bunch of times in future"? Why not have the correct data type and insert the right values?

Comment: I think this is what we'll end up going with, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In sqlSever:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
EmployeeID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
,FirstName VARCHAR(50) NULL
,MiddleName VARCHAR(50) NULL
,LastName VARCHAR(50) NULL
,DateHired datetime NOT NULL
)

-- Change the datatype to support 100 characters and make NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
ALTER COLUMN FirstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

-- Change datatype and allow NULLs for DateHired
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
ALTER COLUMN DateHired SMALLDATETIME NULL

-- Set SPARSE columns for Middle Name (sql server 2008 only)
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
ALTER COLUMN MiddleName VARCHAR(100) SPARSE NULL
```

http://sqlserverplanet.com/ddl/alter-table-alter-column